# populate username from cloud firestore to a dropdown menu using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-cloud-firestore

i have created a registration form using html css and javascript when i click in login button it will display a dropdown menu in another window where all the register username will display in the drop down menu.

i have created another html page and create a dropdown menu but how i can,t understand how to retrieve username fro cloudfirestore to the dropdownmenu[enter image description here]
[enter image description here][1]

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>LogIn</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.2.1/css/fontawesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-QYIZto+st3yW+o8+5OHfT6S482Zsvz2WfOzpFSXMF9zqeLcFV0/wlZpMtyFcZALm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css" integrity="sha384-b6lVK+yci+bfDmaY1u0zE8YYJt0TZxLEAFyYSLHId4xoVvsrQu3INevFKo+Xir8e" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="form-box">
        <h1 id="title">Sign up</h1>
        <form action="">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-field">
                    <i class="bi bi-person-fill"></i>
                    <input type="text" id="userName" placeholder="User Name">
                </div>
                <div class="input-field" id="email">
                    <i class="bi bi-envelope-fill"></i>
                    <input type="email" id="Email" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
                <div class="input-field">
                    <i class="bi bi-lock-fill"></i>
                    <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <div class="input-field" id="phoneNumber">
                    <i class="bi bi-phone-fill"></i>
                    <input type="tel" id="mobileNumber" placeholder="Mobile No">
                </div>
                <p>Forget Password <a href="#">Click here</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-field">
                <button type="button" id="signupBtn">Sign Up</button>
                <button type="button" class="disable" id="signinBtn">Sign In</button>    
            </div>
            
        </form>
      </div>  
    </div>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.8/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script>
        const firebaseConfig = {
          apiKey: "AIzaSyD2izIZyRC1IKqfc5RaZ-HHx0CmxTYNNws",
          authDomain: "login-with-firebase-data-ae61f.firebaseapp.com",
          projectId: "login-with-firebase-data-ae61f",
          storageBucket: "login-with-firebase-data-ae61f.appspot.com",
          messagingSenderId: "905524976644",
          appId: "1:905524976644:web:643932fd262d0b89346951"
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        const auth = firebase.auth()
        const db = firebase.firestore();
    </script>
    <script src="myScript.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: You should use the code snippet function instead of screenshoting all your codes.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)